# Passing JSON to another view controller

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, segue, viewcontroller

I'm having a hard time trying to pass JSON to another view controller using a segue. So for I have only been able to use prepare(for segue, sender), but I can't get my data to populate my outlets on my view controller. Below is my first view controller. Within the prepare(for segue, sender) method you can see my commented out code that's not working. Any advice?

class ViewController2 : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
var pictures : [Hit] = []


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    NetworkMananger.shared.getInfo { [weak self] (results) in
        guard let self = self else {return }
        
        switch results {
        
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            
        case .success(let pictures):
            self.pictures = pictures
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ViewController1"{
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController1
            //                vc.downloadLabel = String(pictures[indexPath.row].downloads)
            //                vc.tagsLabel = pictures[indexPath.row].tags
            //                vc.imageData = UIImage(named: pictures[indexPath.row].previewURL)
        }
        
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController1") as? ViewController1
    
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pictures.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell123", for: indexPath) as! firstTableViewCell
    cell.label?.text = String(pictures[indexPath.row].downloads)
    cell.downloadPictureFromURL(from: pictures[indexPath.row].previewURL)
    
    return cell
    
}
```

}

Below is my second view controller I want to pass my JSON to :

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

```
var picture : Hit!



@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var imageData:
    UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tagsLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var downloadLabel: UILabel!
var cap : String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

}
```

JSON

```
  struct Response : Codable {
  let hits : [Hit]
  }

 struct Hit : Codable  {
 let tags : String
 let previewURL : String
 let downloads : Int
 }
```

Comment: Where does a guy named 'pictures' come from, and what is it?  What does it have to do with JSON or whatever you are trying to pass to another view controller?

Comment: @ElTomato yes it's coming from an API. I will attach it to the code above if you could help me.

Comment: @ElTomato previewURL is a string returning an image, I have a HTTP request to get it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things getting in your way:

1. Right now, in your commented code, you have a type mismatch with each property you're trying to set. For example, you're trying to set a `String` to `downloadLabel`, which is a `UILabel`.
2. At the time of `prepareForSegue`, the `IBOutlets` may not be loaded.

To get around these issues, you could set properties on `ViewController1` and then initialize the views in `viewDidLoad`:

```
struct ViewController1Input {
    var downloadLabelText : String
    var tagsLabelText: String
    var imageName: String
}

class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    var picture : Hit! //careful here -- I'm not sure where this is coming from and you aren't setting it in your segue
    
    var input : ViewController1Input?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageData: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tagsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var downloadLabel: UILabel!
    var cap : String = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let input = input {
            downloadLabel.text = input.downloadLabelText
            tagsLabel.text = input.tagsLabelText
            imageData.image = UIImage(named: input.imageName)
        }
    }
}
```

And in your segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ViewController1"{
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController1
            vc.input = ViewController1Input(downloadLabelText: String(pictures[indexPath.row].downloads),
                                            tagsLabelText: pictures[indexPath.row].tags,
                                            imageName: pictures[indexPath.row].previewURL)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I probably should of mentioned the data is coming from an API, I attached the network class below.

Comment: Did you try the approach I explained? Where the information comes from won’t affect it.